# Meteor - unable to insert record into db - insert failed: Method '/post/insert' not found

Tags: meteor

I am unable to add record to the db via console:

```
Post.insert({content: 'This is some content', date: new Date() })
```

I get following error message:
insert failed: Method '/post/insert' not found

Looking at the terminal all seems fine:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Can anyone help with this. I am stuck and don't know how to move further.

Comment: How are you trying to use console for db operations? Have you used "meteor mongo" and then "show dbs" and "use db" ?

Comment: Yes I am using mongo via meteor. And the console is the console in the dev tools in chromium browser. I am following course and I did all from A-Z as per course, but I have noticed that this is new version of meteor.

Comment: Oh, I do not think that you can use dev tools in chrome as a mongo shell console. Use operating system console (CLI) through which you would have started meteor dev server by running command meteor. Open a new console which is different from the one running meteor server. In new console, run command meteor mongo which should take you in the mongo shell where you can run DB commands.

Comment: Can you show how did you create the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Goto your `Post` collection declaration and add this below definition,

```
Post.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc){
    //allow only if userId exists.
    return !!userId;
  }
});
```

This will cause query fired from Chrome console to work.